# Different between "Sites" vs "teams" in SharePoint online URL

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am a bit confused in terms of the Microsoft Team URL and SharePoint online URL. Can you please help me to answer the below questions:

- Can I see Microsoft Teams URL in SharePoint Admin under Active sites?
- If the SharePoint URL includes "Teams" does it means this is Microsoft Team and not SharePoint site?
- How to differentiate Microsoft Team URL and SharePoint URL?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Yes, you can find SharePoint Online sites associated with Teams using SharePoint Admin Center under Active sites.

[image]

2)The SharePoint URL contains "Team", which does not mean that it is a Microsoft Team and not a SharePoint site. **Office 365 provisions every the group created for each team with a SharePoint Online site collection.** Microsoft seems to be moving away from referring to collections, possibly because the wide majority of collections are created from Office 365 Groups and Teams and therefore hold one site.

3)If the SharePoint URL contains "Team", then this site will display Microsoft Teams icon.

[image]